# Prepare for segue inside of for loop

Tags: ios, swift

I have a table view with the following `willSelectRowAt` code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
    for n in 0...carsArray.count - 1 {
        if indexPath.row == n {
            print(carsArray[n].name)
            func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
                if segue.identifier == "goToEditCar" {
                    let name = carsArray[n].name
                    print(name)
                    let indexCar = n

                    let destinationVC = segue.destination as! EditCarViewController
                    destinationVC.name = name
                    destinationVC.indexCar = indexCar
                }
            }

            performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToEditCar", sender: self)
        }
    }
}
```

Somehow the `prepare` function won't pass the desired data, neither will it `print(name)` - **can anyone tell me the issue with this piece of code?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code cannot work at all. You are using the wrong API, `prepare(for` is never going to be called inside another method and actually you don't need a loop.

`willSelectRowAt` is to control if a cell is allowed to be selected. Return the `indexPath` if it's allowed otherwise return `nil`

This is not what you want. Use `didSelect` and pass the index path as `sender` when calling `performSegue`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToEditCar", sender: indexPath)
}
```

In `prepare(for` get the index path from the `sender` parameter

```
func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "goToEditCar" {
       let indexPath = sender as! IndexPath
       let name = carsArray[indexPath.row].name
       print(name)

       let destinationVC = segue.destination as! EditCarViewController
       destinationVC.name = name
       destinationVC.indexCar = indexPath.row
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a for-loop here as `n` eventually will be equal to `indexPath.row` also you should use `didSelectRowAt`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) { 
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToEditCar", sender:indexPath.row) 
}

 func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "goToEditCar" { 
            let index = sender as! Int
            let destinationVC = segue.destination as! EditCarViewController
            destinationVC.name = carsArray[index].name
            destinationVC.indexCar = index
        }
}
```